# Checking for network availability not working

Tags: android, android-wifi

I use the following code to check the network status of an android device ([Source](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html))

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
      getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

After running it on my phone, I find that it does return "true" when network is available. But when I turn on the Airplane Mode on my phone, I find that it still returns "true". What is wrong here? Also, does a "true" mean that the wifi is also on or just that cellular network is available?

Thanks

PS: And yes, I have added the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. True value means that there is internet connection from wifi or cellular network. You can have air plane mode on but if you still have wifi on your method will return true. 
See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected()